# How to send an email message using Microsoft Exchange Server from Sql Server 2005/2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I know how to send mail using an SMTP server specified in a mail profiler in the Database Mail of Sql Server.

You would do it like so:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  @profile_name = 'profile',
                              @recipients = @email,
                              @body = @body,
                              @body_format = 'HTML',
                              @subject = @subject
```

But I don't know how to send mail using Microsoft Exchange.

**Update 1.** 
I believe that the main problem of my not being able to send mail through Exchange is that it's using the NTLM-based authentication. And I most certainly don't want my Sql Server running using my domain user credentials.

**Update 2.**
Thank you for your suggestions. Here's the catch. I don't have any control whatsoever over the corporate Exchange Server in question. So the only course of action would be to try to impersonate me on the Exchange endpoint somehow. Luckily, I can communicate with the Exchange via telnet ip-of-the-exchange-server 25.

Comment: Hmm... if you don't have any control over the Exchange Server, the easiest solution might be to just use your internet provider's SMTP server...

Comment: But what if the only way out is this corporate mail. Everything is blocked except for the Exchange and this proxy server through which I go to the intertubes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use your Exchange Server's IP as the STMP server in SQL Server and
- configure Exchange Server's SMTP connector to allow relaying for the IP of your SQL Server.

Follow the link for instructions on [how to do this with Exchange Server 2003 and 2007](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31768555/how-to-allow-relay-from-internal-smtp-device-in-exchange-2007.aspx).

**Regarding your Update**: If you do it like described above (allow relaying), you don't need any credentials. Every process *on your SQL Server's machine* will be allowed to send mail through your Exchange Server, without any authorization.

Here are some general hints to debug an SMTP connection. To test this configuration, you could open a command line on your SQL Server and use `telnet` to create an SMTP session (you have to type the lines that do not begin with a number):

```
C:\>telnet ip-of-your-exchange-server 25
220 your.domain Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 6.0.3790.4675 ready at  Thu, 2 Sep 2010 16:19:33 +0200
EHLO heinzi
250-your.domain Hello [192.168.3.1]
250-TURN
[...]
250-XEXCH50
250 OK
MAIL FROM:<your@email.address>
250 2.1.0 your@email.address....Sender OK
RCPT TO:<some.other.address@outside.your.domain>
```

After the last line, your receive either of two answers. This one means that everything is fine:

```
250 2.1.5 some.other.address@outside.your.domain
```

This one (or a similar one) means that you have still not configured your Exchange Server correctly:

```
554 5.7.1 <some.other.address@outside.your.domain>: Relay access denied
```

Answer (score 1):

Exchange is just another SMTP server.  You point your profile to the specifics of your server, and you're done.  I do it every day in my environment.  Is SMTP disabled for some reason on your Exchange instance?